# PDO::FETCH_ASSOC Does not return the correct table columns

Tags: pdo

I'm new to PHP and I am currently developing a small web application. Below is the test code for the DB query using PDO:

```
try 
{
    $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=auction";
    $opt = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
    );
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'password', $opt);
}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT id,username,password,name,level FROM users");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$test = $stmt->fetchALL();
print_r($test);
```

The output of the said code is the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => admin [users] => Administrator [auction] => 0 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [username] => jodel [users] => Jodel Ross [auction] => 1 ) )
```

I am confused because, from my point of view, the above code should have given an associative array whose index are the columns of the returned result set, i.e. id, username,password,name,level. But it is not so.

Moreover, If I used PDO::FETCH_NUM, the correct number of fields and corresponding data are returned correctly as show below:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 
                       [1] => admin 
                       [2] => 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 
                       [3] => Administrator 
                       [4] => 0 )
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 
                       [1] => jodel_ross 
                       [2] => 2cdaeb5df4cf941d9c5650591cba1fdc 
                       [3] => Jodel Ross, Jr. 
                       [4] => 1 ) )
```

Please help, I need to understand why and I have search the web for answers and have not found any.
Thanks.

```
Development environment:
Windows 7 x64
PHP 5.3.6 
Mysql 5.5 
Apache 2.0.64 
Zend Framework 1.11
```

Answer (score 1):

There is still an open error with Zend Framework 1.x, PHP 5.3.x and setFetchMode() and that's the reason why it doesn't work as expected.

see http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10866 and http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-3470

Please vote for closing this error or submit a patch.