# Why is my code making PDO return nested arrays?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo, multidimensional-array

I'm sure I must be doing something wrong, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere (at least neither in the documentation nor on SO as of yet). I am a beginner in PHP and SQL.

I have this simple table called "mObject_has_media" with only two columns "media_idMedia" and "mObject_idmObject"

When I try to query the table with this code,

```
public function selectMediaIds (MObject $object) {
    $medias = array ();
    $req = $this -> _db -> query ('SELECT media_idMedia FROM mObject_has_media WHERE mObject_idmObject = ' . $object -> id ());
    while ($data = $req -> fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $medias[] = $data;
    }
    $req -> closeCursor ();
    return $medias;
}
```

the problem is this: when I var_dump the contents of the method's result, I get:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'media_idMedia' => string '52' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'media_idMedia' => string '53' (length=2)
```

I'd like to get rid of those nested arrays and just get something like:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 'media_idMedia' => string '52' (length=2)
  1 => 'media_idMedia' => string '53' (length=2)
```

so I can simply run this array into a foreach loop right afterwards... I'm sure that this problem has everything to do with the fetch() method, but in spite of experimenting with different options, I haven't been able to get the desired behavior.

A similar question (I think) was asked here: [PDO::FETCH_ASSOC Does not return the correct table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682691/pdofetch-assoc-does-not-return-the-correct-table-columns) but the answer mentioned the Zend framework, and I am NOT using any framework at all, this is just vanilla PHP.

Comment: `0 => 'media_idMedia' => string '52' (length=2)` makes no sense. That isn't a real data structure, but the closest thing it resembles is a *nested array*, which you claim to be trying to avoid. You can have a string key, or a numeric key, but you can't have a numeric key pointing at a string key pointing at a value. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oops sorry, I just made that up to show what I was aiming for, but I forgot to delete part of the output I was getting. What I meant was that I just want an array with 0 => firstID, 1 => 2ndID and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a multi-dimensional array just for testing purposes:

```
$array = array(
    array('foo' => 'value1'),
    array('foo' => 'value2')
);
```

Now consider the following code:

```
$result = array();

while ($row = array_shift($array)) {
    // $row will contain one nested array at a time
    $result[] = $row;
}

print_r($result);
```

`$row` is an array, and with the statement `$result[] = $row;`, you're pushing the entire array to `$result` thereby making it multi-dimensional.

This would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foo] => value1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [foo] => value2
        )

)
```

Now, consider the following code:

```
$result = array();

while ($row = array_shift($array)) {
    // $row will contain one nested array at a time
    $result[] = $row['foo'];
}

print_r($result);
```

With the statement `$result[] = $row['foo'];`, we are pushing the **value** `$row['foo']` to the `$result` array. At the end of loop iteration, `$result` will hold an array of `foo` row values.

This would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/116206)

---

To fix your original code, you can modify it like so:

```
$medias[] = $data['media_idMedia'];
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation! Works like a charm :D

Answer (score 1):

**The parameter** `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` **tells PDO to return the result as an associative array.**

**PDO::FETCH_ASSOC will return an array as shown in your code., except that if there are multiple columns with the same name, the value referred to by that key will be an array of all the values in the row that had that column name**

I think this line of code

```
while ($data = $req -> fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ }
$data = $req -> fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
 `$data`, itself is returned as an array.
```

This means you don't need to define another array just use $data

Something like

```
 $req = $this -> _db -> query ('SELECT media_idMedia FROM mObject_has_media WHERE mObject_idmObject = ' . $object -> id ());
    while ($data = $req -> fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data['media_idMedia']; //for media id.
    }
```

Comment: Mmmmmmmm maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I var_dump the contents of $data['media_idMedia'] after the while loop, I get a null / a boolean at false (I don't remember which, I've been var_dumping stuff all evening to check whether my script was behaving correctly...)

Comment: For anyone wondering, `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);` will fetch all the rows and put all the rows as strings in one array, instead of a multidimensional array